# format of a https get request

Tags: http, https

format of a https get request

I was trying to implement a HTTPS get request.

This is my sample HTTP get request.

```
GET example.com HTTP/1.1
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 1857 12:27:07 GMT
Host: xyz.com:5901
User-Agent:
Content-Length:  0
```

I have used SSL library to encrypt the message, but is there anyway to differentiate a HTTP message and https message with the request?
Right now I have put a condition to call the SSL library, but I havent found any example where http request varies from https request.

Can anyone guide me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTPS is [HTTP over SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818). Essentially, the SSL/TLS connection is initiated by the client. Once the SSL/TLS connection is established, it's just like normal HTTP. As the RFC says:

> Conceptually, HTTP/TLS is very simple. Simply use HTTP over TLS
> precisely as you would use HTTP over TCP.

Comment: Thank you ! Spared me a lot of trouble!

Comment: To  add to Bruno, anyone interested can read the RFC on this link  <http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2818>